# dbt pivot multiple columns

Tags: sql, pivot, dbt

I have the following table in my_model.sql:

| NAMES | COUNTRY | DATE | AGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mario | uk | 2021 | 38 |
| robert | uk | 2022 | 18 |
| frank | usa | 2011 | 55 |
| julia | usa | 1999 | 80 |

I need to pivot the table and have the final result as:

| COUNTRY | mario | mario_date | robert | robert_date | frank | frank_date | julia | julia_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| uk | 38 | 2021 | 18 | 2022 | null | null | null | null |
| usa | null | null | null | null | 55 | 2011 | 80 | 1999 |

I have been able to pivot names by doing the following:

```
{% set pivot_cols = dbt_utils.get_column_values(table = ref('my_table'), column = 'names')%}

with pivot as (
select * from {{ ref('my_table')}}
pivot(  max(AGE) for names in ( 
    {% for pivot_col in pivot_cols %}
    '{{pivot_col}}'{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}))

select * from pivot
```

| COUNTRY | mario | robert | frank | julia |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| uk | 38 | 18 | null | null |
| usa | null | null | 55 | 80 |

but I need help with pivoting dates as well to create columns related _date columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can write another pivot query for _date columns just like names' query and then join both pivot queries using country column.